# Annotating classes

Tags: javascript

I would like to use annotate classes in my javascript project. I'm using webpack and everything looks working (project compiles) but annotated classes fails to execute.

```
function annotation(target) {
    target.isAnnotated = true;
}

@annotation()
export class Template {
    constructor(id, name, subject, type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.type = type;
        this.message = '';
    }
}
```

My webpack.config.js uses such configuration options:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
        plugins: [
            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
        ]
    }
}
```

but while runing the code, I get the exception:

```
Cannot set property 'isAnnotated' of undefined
```

Either I can't properly create annotation function or there is something more I need to configure but based on [this](http://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-decorators) it should be working.

Comment: Did you try removing the parentheses from `@annotation`?

Comment: currently js does not support decorators , you need typescript

Comment: @brk …or babel, which the OP is already using

Comment: You are declaring a `target` parameter in that function but you are calling it without arguments: `annotation()` - what did you expect the target to be?

Comment: Isn't `Template` a built-in object?

Comment: @UnholySheep it looks to be working without parentheses (lol). My understanding of decorators is more from C# env than from Javascript